# xcode integration with JIRA for automatic reporting of crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, crash, jira

is there anyway to integrate JIRA with xcode, so that crashes which are reported in xcode->window->organizer->Crashes can be tracked in JIRA automatically.

Answer (score -1):

From the Jira side, the Jira REST API would be the thing to use

Comment: there must be some thing added in xcode which aloing with listing the crash in xcode adds it to JIRA also. If I need to use Jira REST API, there must be a way to call it from xcode